# How do we create an autocard link to a card with an apostrophe in the name?

Tags: support, bug, status-deferred, mtg-autocard

In [Infractions/Player Communication - Infernal Tutor and Lion's Eye Diamond](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/11708/50), it would be nice to link correctly to [Lion's Eye Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3255). Using an apostrophe character, as in `[mtg:Lion's Eye Diamond]` seems to break the autocard markup: [Lion's Eye Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLion%27s%5d%2b%5bEye%5d%2b%5bDiamond%5d). Is there some way to do this, perhaps with explicit character encoding? I had a go, but [wasn't successful](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/11708/revisions).

Two in the same day! `[mtg: Sensei's Divining Top]`, needed in [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/11714/50).

Comment: If we can escape the `%27` it might work, but otherwise I don't know.

Comment: Isn't this related to this question? http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/794/some-autocard-names-dont-execute-correctly

Comment: @Aarthi - Yes. I'm raising it again though because it's a pain, and there's been no satisfactory response to [Alex P's comment](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/794/some-autocard-names-dont-execute-correctly#comment1402_797). While I agree that the API doesn't support the quote, there's absolutely no reason our implementation can't accept the quote char, and then just drop it before calling the API.

Comment: Ok. I'll ask KevinMontrose to take a look at it.

Comment: *Bump* This is a continuing annoyance. Many MTG cards use an apostrophe in their name.

Comment: I think the @Aarthi might have been missing from the "bump". I can never remember exactly who gets notified on these.

Comment: @shujaa - I don't think Aarthi works for SE anymore. I think Abby is now watching over us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Magic card auto link feature be improved?](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/can-the-magic-card-auto-link-feature-be-improved)

Comment: VTC as duplicate of the newer thread, in which this was resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Let's switch to using Magiccards.info instead of the Gatherer for our mtg: links.

Currently they point here:

```
http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name={name}
```

Let's point them here:

```
http://www.magiccards.info/query?q=!{name}
```

It'll work, since they don't drop the apostrophe like the Gatherer does.

- [Kiora's Follower](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Kiora%27s%20follower) using the Gatherer
- [Kiora's Follower](http://magiccards.info/query?q=!Kiora%27s%20follower) using Magiccards.info

The [MTG Salvation Wiki](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Main_Page) uses Maggicards.info instead of the Gatherer, and this bug is probably why. It's a little crummy having to either make people compensate for broken links, or use improper names like [Kiora Follower](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Kiora%20Follower) to get around it.

#### What's that ! there for?

It's the exact match flag. Compare:

- With a bang, only the card you specified turns up: http://magiccards.info/query?q=!Pox
- Without a bang, others do too: http://magiccards.info/query?q=Pox

#### This also handles specific cards better.

See how the Gatherer handles these: [Inkmoth Nexus](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Inkmoth%20Nexus) and [Pox](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Pox).

Compared to Magiccards.info: [Inkmoth Nexus](http://www.magiccards.info/query?q=!Inkmoth+Nexus) and [Pox](http://www.magiccards.info/query?q=!Pox)

Comment: So far, I can't find any cards that don't work. Apostrophes work. Commas work. Magic's AE thing works. I guess the only issue is a bit of a legal question.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is internal to Wizards' website - their public card search drops the apostrophe instead of passing it on. The link is already encoded correctly - they're just stripping punctuation for some unknown reason<sup>*</sup>.

If they ever fix this, we're already sending them the right input so it'll just start working.

As a work-around, just drop the possessive:  [Sensei's Divining Top](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=%20Sensei%27s%20Divining%20Top) ->  [Sensei Divining Top](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=%20Sensei%20Divining%20Top)

<sup>*<sub>my money's on crappy input sanitizing</sub></sup>

Comment: Frankly: a lot of things about the Wizards website is pretty terrible. INCLUDING THEIR TOS. *shakes fist*

Comment: I already know this. So why can't *we* (StackExchange) strip the apostrophe before sending it to the broken API? The work-around is lame. It looks like a typo.

Comment: Couldn't we copy the way MTG itself displays cards?  `<a class="nodec" keyname="name" keyvalue="Giant_Growth" onmouseover="OpenTip(event, this)" onclick="autoCardWindow(this)" href="javascript:void()">Giant Growth</a>` The auto-popup window is **really** nice.

Comment: See aarthi's comment about Wizards' TOS above, @Andomar. We'd have to violate it in order to do that - and yes, lots of other sites do so, but we're not interested in the liability; if they change their TOS, we can implement it.

Comment: @ire_and_curses This seems to have been forgotten, but "community" just bumped this, so I thought I'd chime in and say **strongly agree** with your comment.